# java web application with glassfish has not been deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

At my first try web application in java in netbeans have error like this.

> Starting GlassFish Server
>
> GlassFish Server is running.
>
> In-place deployment at
>   C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DateWebApplication\build\web
>   GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
>   C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DateWebApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1071:
>   The module has not been deployed.
>
> See the server log for details.

I'm tried running asadmin.bat in glassfish folder and typed start-domain.After that working & displaying on browser but said need full jdk not only jre. I did  reinstall jre.And install jdk.This doesnt work. After after that tried java home to java jdk at asadmin.bat in glassfish. After that asadmin doesnt work anymore. And has not been deployed error insist. What can I do?

Comment: As the message says: See the server.log for details.

Comment: tons of logs am stuck